# Can I put batteries as checkpoints?

Tags: batteries, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, inverter, solar-energy

I'd like to make sure the voltage along a DC system of a building keeps stable. 
Consider I have the main power station with solar input current and main batteries.

Can I put batteries in parallel along the circuit where more load is expected?
Do they align to the same voltage even though they are far away from each other?

I'd like to do such thing to lower dissipation on main cables and also to put AC only where needed.

I'm asking this because placing an inverter far away from the batteries caused it to lose power. So I thought I could place a backup battery in parallel right before it.

What are common practices about this problem?

Comment: Batteries can be closest to the load for best results as long as PV has a reverse blocking diode for dark conditions.

Comment: What voltage are your batteries, and what type are they?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt That's the case. PV panels all have reverse blocking diodes. The system has a charge regulator with three channels: PV panels, batteries, load. Backup batteries would be on the load circuit. Maybe blocking diodes are needed also on the load channel of the charge regulator, to prevent reverse voltage when the load switch is set to OFF?

Comment: @BeB00 I have two 12V, 150Ah lead batteries as the main source. Then I've got countless car batteries.

Comment: The only issue might be cable losses. So far OK

Comment: What is the dc voltage that you are distributing? How do you plan to charge the batteries?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson That's 12V for now. The charging part leaves me wondering: is attaching the batteries to the circuit enough to charge them (sucking from the main batteries, through the load of the charge regulator), or do I have to add a charge regulator for each secondary battery?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt Indeed global loss is not my concern. I'm almost always on full battery charge given sun exposition. My problem is peak power not being transferred.

Answer (score 1):

The batteries may be considered as lossy supercaps add a low ESR 100uF (optional) both near the loads.

> > 100k Farads new, 1% when dead with higher ESR.  This helps supply motor start surge current and suppress turn off spikes

Answer (score 0):

You will have some problems with this approach. Attaching lead-acid batteries to a 12V dc distribution will not charge them, and they will likely be the main source of current rather than a backup or supplement. You'll have to remove them for charging fairly often, I would think.

Putting voltage sources in parallel is always tricky. If your batteries are not exactly the same and charged the same then a battery with a slightly higher voltage will end up charging a nearby battery with a lower voltage, rather than supplying power to your load. Under worst case conditions a very high current (tens of amperes) might flow between the batteries, leading to unsafe heating in your wiring.

Comment: I agree, and also each battery in parallel sees a different output resistance. What you should do here is to insert a DC-DC frontend in series  to each battery which controls charging and discharging of each battery separately. Or you can "simply" add input capacitance to your inverter.